# Server Error in '/' Application 404 Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I'm new to C# and .NET. I've developed a web solution in Visual Studio that works well when I run the preview in VS.  I have moved the files over to my server and am now getting the error :

"Server Error in '/' Application with a 404 error.

My .NET framework in my application pool matches my web.config file. Any ideas of other things to check?

Comment: Are you sure you're going to a valid location? Are you using a virtual directory, or sub directory of any sort?

Comment: Can you post the rest of the error? Does it have a description as well?

Comment: please verify your app framework and your IIS framework

Comment: Go on your IIS and try browsing your site from there. It could be you're hitting the wrong URL.

Comment: 404 sounds like a path configuration issue. You get that at site root, or when navigating to a specific page?

Comment: I can get to the site root no problem.  I get this error once I try to go to any page in that directory.

Comment: Also, I will add that the page I am trying to go to is inside the /Views folder.  From what I have read, you can't go to anything inside the views folder directly. How would I navigate to that page instead?